# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Getting the below error while running the Azure Function:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Thanks,
Shrikant

Comment: Which version of Azure-Function are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The error you gave can happen for multiple reason, but without more information, the most likely case is that the code you wrote for your Azure Function depends on `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault`. This is not one of our included default dependencies, so you need to explicitly include this assembly as a dependency. How to do this depends whether you are using pre-compiled C#, or a C# script (.csx).

**Pre-compiled**

In the [pre-compiled case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library) with Visual Studio, just including the reference as part of the `.csproj` file for your library should be sufficient to get rid of this error.

**C# script (.csx)**

In .csx files, you need to load in external .dll files using the `#r` notation. You can read more about what assemblies are included by default [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies). For assemblies not included by default, you would need to do the following:

1. Include a `project.json` file in your function's folder in the application's file system that looks like:

> {   "frameworks": {
>       "net46":{
>         "dependencies": {
>           "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault": "1.1.0"
>          }
>        }    } }

2. Include `#r "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault"` at the top of your .csx file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. i have included the dll in the pre-complie version and available in the Dependecies==>Assemblies and the version of the key Vault 3.0.0.0 and Azure Function V2 - still getting the error. is it related to version of my Azure Function?